# Change domain expire-date on all domains on Plesk 11 API

Tags: dns, plesk

I have more than 100 domains on a Plesk 11 server, I created them on Default Service Plans, but they expire every year. I updated the default Service Plans and set Expiration date to Unlimited but how to I apply to all domains using Default Service Plans?

I have tried changing Service Plans and sync but domain Renewal date does not change.

Is there a way to do it using Plesk API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

via API-RPC:

```
# cat x.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<packet version="1.6.3.0">
    <webspace>
        <set>
           <filter/>
           <values>
               <limits>
                   <limit>

                       <name>expiration</name>

                       <value>-1</value>

                   </limit>
               </limits>
           </values>
        </set>
    </webspace>
</packet>

# curl -kv -XPOST -H "HTTP_AUTH_LOGIN: admin" -H "HTTP_AUTH_PASSWD: password"  -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d @x.xml https://localhost:8443/enterprise/control/agent.php
```

via CLI:

```
# for sub in `ls /var/www/vhosts/` ; do  /usr/local/psa/bin/subscription_settings -u $sub -expiration -1 ; done
```

Comment: Thanks for help do you know how to implement this solution using RPC API?

Comment: Not recommended but I also find a solution by changing values in database.      `use psa; update Limits set ``value``='-1' where limit_name= 'expiration';`

Answer (score 0):

You can easyly change subscription date by

1. Login in to plesk by reseller login details
2. Click on Subscriptions
3. Select any domain Click on Customized Then go to Bottom of page and
   change to new coming date
4. Click Update and lock.

See this video for more:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkRfnJRpMdc

Comment: Hi, that only change subscription for only one domain at a time. I have 300 domains on server and needed to change them all quickly.

Comment: @Faraz you can use any billing system like WHMCS, WHM Autopilot etc, they are controlling by API. so by this you can easily mange it.